# gvsig raster image misplaced in leaflet, projection problem?

Tags: raster, gdal, leaflet, raster-conversion, gvsig

I am trying to show in leaflet a geotiff raster image that was generated in gvSig.
The basemap I am using in leaflet is a wms server with projection EPSG:3857.

Leaflet needs to know the upper right and bottom left corners in latitude and longitude coordinates which I get from the tfw file.

When I add my raster image the south west and north east corners are displayed in the correct position (the ones I specify to leaflet), but the other two are not. And most of the image is not displayed at the correct position either.
It seems there is a problem with the projections.

gdalinfo of the raster file shows:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: ModCombustible.tif
Size is 600, 945
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 30N",
    GEOGCS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-3],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","25830"]]
Origin = (713179.879402380902320,4381253.375599999912083)
Pixel Size = (5.001750158730428,-5.001750158730441)
```

I tried to use gdalwarp to reproject the raster in EPSG:3857 with the command:
 `gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 ModCombustible.tif ModCombustible_3857.tif`

but in the tfw file I am getting negative UTM easting coordinates which doesn't make any sense to me.

What should I do to properly show the raster image in leaflet?

**EDIT**: The negative easting coordinates are correct for the EPSG:3857 if they are west of London. Using the link provided by the user30184 I could translate the coordinates to latitude and longitude and show the image at the correct position.

**EDIT2**: To clarify basic concepts which were not clear to me: as IvanSanchez mentioned in the comments, UTM (Universal Transverse Mercator) is a system of 60 different projections using false easting and northing. In the other hand Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) is not UTM but uses easting and northing coordinates to define a position. It is the de facto standard for web map applications.

Comment: If you are west to London then EPSG:3857 eastings are negative http://epsg.io/map#srs=3857&x=-450061.222543&y=4872401.930340&z=5

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that EPSG:3857 can be negative. In the link you provided I could transform to lat long and load the raster in leaflet at the correct position :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, use the `-s_srs` option of `gdalwarp` to force a source SRS for the warping, e.g.:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:25830 -t_srs EPSG:3857 ModCombustible.tif ModCombustible_3857.tif
```

Comment: Thank you. I added the source SRS but I keep getting negative utm coordinates
Upper Left  (  -57917.696, 4801412.920) (  0d31'13.02"W, 39d33'16.20"N)
Lower Left  (  -57917.696, 4795165.270) (  0d31'13.02"W, 39d30'40.37"N)
Upper Right (  -53865.167, 4801412.920) (  0d29' 1.96"W, 39d33'16.20"N)
Lower Right (  -53865.167, 4795165.270) (  0d29' 1.96"W, 39d30'40.37"N)
Center      (  -55891.431, 4798289.095) (  0d30' 7.49"W, 39d31'58.29"N)

Comment: Don't call the UTM coordinates, they are EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) coordinates, and propably just right.

Comment: I am a bit confused with the vocabulary, I thought that UTM was an umbrella term for any Easting Northing projection. But I guess it is a map projection itself and each UTM zone has its own EPSG code. Is that correct? In that case I will edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: No, UTM stands for [Universal Transverse Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system). It has a false easting and false northing, but other projections (such as polar stereographic) also do.
UTM is not a projection; UTM is a system of 60 different but obviously similar projections and CRSs.